# mysql: 'WHERE something!=true' excludes fields with NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a 2 tables, one in which I have groups, the other where I set user restrictions of which groups are seen.
When I do LEFT JOIN and specify no condition, it shows me all records. When I do WHERE group_hide.hide!='true' it only shows these records that have false enum type set to them. With JOIN, other groups get the hide field set as "NULL".
How can I make it so that it excludes only these that are set to true, and show everything else that has either NULL or false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL you must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` when dealing with nullable values.

HEre you should use `(group_hide.hide IS NULL OR group_hide.hide != 'true')`

Comment: See [Working with NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Don already provided good answer to the question that you asked and will solve your immediate problem.

However, let me address the point of wrong data type domain. Normally you would make `hide` be BOOLEAN but mysql does not really implement it completely. It converts it to TINYINT(1) which allows values from -128 to 127 (see overview of [data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) for mysql). Since mysql does not support CHECK constraint you are left with options to either use a trigger or foreign reference to properly enforce the domain.

Here are the problems with wrong data domain (your case), in order of importance:

- The disadvantages of allowing NULL for a field that can be only 1 or 0 are that you have to employ [3 value logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) (true, false, null), which btw is not perfectly implemented in SQL. This makes certain query more *complex* and *slower* then they need to be. If you can make a column NOT NULL, do.
- The disadvantages of using VARCHAR for a field that can be only 1 or 0 are the speed of the query, due to the extra I/O and bigger storage needs (slows down reads, writes, makes indexes bigger if a field is part of the index and influences the size of backups; keep in mind that *none* of these effects might be noticeable with wrong domain of a *single* field for a *smaller* size tables, but if data types are consistently set too big or if the table has serious number of records the effects will bite). Also, you will always need to convert the VARCHAR to a 1 or 0 to use natural mysql boolean operators increasing complexity of queries.
- The disadvantage of mysql using TINYINT(1) for BOOL is that certain values are allowed by RDBMS that should not be allowed, theoretically allowing for meaningless values to be stored in the system. In this case your application layer must guarantee the data integrity and it is always better if RDBMS guarantees integrity as it would protect you from certain bugs in application layer and also mistakes that might be done by database administrator.

Answer (score 0):

an obvious answer would be:

```
WHERE (group_hide.hide is null or group_hide.hide ='false')
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head what the null behaviour rules are.